# Unexpected Token in JSX (React Component)

Tags: redux, react-redux, reactjs, jsx

I am sorry if this is the wrong place to ask something like this, but I cannot find this error for the life of me. I even slept on it and tried for another couple hours this morning.

This is my error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/results_instructor_view/weekly_report_results_instructor.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Temple/Source/Workspaces/LMS/TechAcademyLMS/TechAcademyLMS/Scripts/React-Redux-App/src/components/results_instructor_view/weekly_report_results_instructor.js: Unexpected token, expected , (139:4)

  137 |
  138 |
> 139 |                 } else {
      |                   ^
  140 |
  141 |                         return (<h6>No weekly reports yet</h6>);
  142 |                 }

 @ ./src/containers/main_display_container.js 85:40-121
 @ ./src/components/app.js
 @ ./src/routes.js
 @ ./src/Index.js
```

This is my code:

```
// libraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Loader
import Loader from '../../components/loader/loader';

//actions
import { resultsInstructorViewAction } from '../../actions/Results/results_instructor_view_action';




class WeeklyReportResult extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // getting the user info from the props/params
        const userInfo = this.props.match.params.value.split(',');
        // url for the getWeeklyReport
        const url = `/SPA/getWeeklyReport?Id=${userInfo[1]}`;

        this.props.resultsInstructorViewAction(url);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

        // set loaded to true
        if (this.state.Loaded === false) {

            this.setState({ Loaded: true });
        }

    }



    render() {


        // checking to see if the data exists
        if (this.props.resultsInstructorView > [0]) {
            const renderList = this.props.resultsInstructorView.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                    // Key for error in console due to mapping
                    <div key={i}>
                        <hr className="style-two" />
                        <h4>Date Submitted: </h4><p>{item.Date}</p>
                        <h5>Course Position: </h5><p>{item.CoursePosition}</p>
                        <h5>Need Help: </h5><p>{item.NeedHelp}</p>
                        <h5>Materials and Supplies Needed: </h5><p>{item.MaterialsAndSupplies}</p>
                        <h5>Meetups: </h5><p>{item.Meetups}</p>
                        <h5>Positive Experiences: </h5><p>{item.Positives}</p>
                        <h5>Complaints: </h5><p>{item.Complaints}</p>
                        <h5>Hours Studied: </h5><p>{item.HoursStudied}</p>
                        <h5>Job Search: </h5><p>{item.JobSearch}</p>
                        <h5>Referral: </h5><p>{item.Referral}</p>
                        <h5>Miscellaneous: </h5><p>{item.Miscellaneous}</p>


                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-lg" onClick={this.toggleModal} id={item.DailyReportId}>
                                Give Feedback
                    </button>
                    </div>
            );
        });
    } 




                    // building the already responded daily reports
const renderAllList = this.props.resultsInstructorView.map((item, i) => {
    if (item.Feedbacks.length > 0) {

        return (

            <Panel key={i} header={item.Date} eventKey={i} bsStyle="primary" className="text-center">
                <hr className="style-two" />
                <div className="text-left">
                    <h6><strong>Date Submitted :</strong> {item.Date}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Course Position : </strong>{item.CoursePosition}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Need Help : </strong>{item.NeedHelp}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Materials and Supplies :</strong> {item.MaterialsAndSupplies}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Positives : </strong>{item.Positives}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Complaints :</strong> {item.Complaints}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Hours Studied :</strong> {item.HoursStudied}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Job Search :</strong> {item.JobSearch}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Referral :</strong> {item.Referral}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Miscellaneous :</strong> {item.Miscellaneous}</h6>
                    <h6><strong>Instructor Feedback : </strong><mark>{item.Feedbacks[0].Content}</mark></h6>
                </div>

            </Panel>
        );
}






            return (
                <div className="container text-center">

                    <div className="row">
                        <h1>Weekly Reports</h1>
                        <h3>Student Name: </h3><h5>{this.props.match.params.value.split(',')[2]}</h5>

                    </div>

                    <div className="col-sm-12 text-left">

                        {renderList}


                        <hr className="style-two" />
                            <h2 className="text-center">Past Reports</h2>

                            <Accordion>
                                {renderAllList}
                            </Accordion>
                            <FeedbackModal
                                show={this.state.isOpen}
                                toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
                                name={this.props.match.params.value.split(',')[0]}
                                id={this.props.match.params.value.split(',')[1]}
                                weeklyReportId={this.state.tempId}

                            />

                    </div>

                </div>

            );


        } else {

            return (<h6>No weekly reports yet</h6>);
        }

    }
    }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { resultsInstructorView: state.ResultsInstructorView };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        resultsInstructorViewAction
    }, dispatch);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WeeklyReportResult);
```

Comment: Debugging syntax errors would be significantly easier if you formatted/indented your code consistently.

Comment: I have VS 15 bro, it doesn't format code @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: Then maybe switch to an editor that understands JS syntax?

Comment: I would if company rules allowed it @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: That's no company Tony Stark would work for, I will tell you that much.

Comment: BTW, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334522.aspx), VS 2015 supports JS.  Either way, Stack Overflow is not a linting service :/

Comment: @Frosty619 Tony has to pay the bills haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The else statement should go before the second return statement, like so:

```
render() {
   if (this.props.resultsInstructorView > [0]) {
 return (
//code here
);
} else {
return (
  //code here.
 );
}
```

Comment: Bro I still can't find it haha

Comment: @TonyStark You currently have a code that looks a bit like this:
```
if (item.Feedbacks.length > 0) {
  return (<Panel>...</Panel>)
}

return (<div className="container text-center">...</div>)

else {
  return (<h6>...</h6>)
}
```
That middle `return` statement makes the `else` statement unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you first ought to work on fixing up the formatting for that code - it would help make it easier to read and find issues :)

The `}` right before the `else` currently matches up with the `{` for the `resultsInstructorview.map()` call, so that's not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it seems like you're missing a closing bracket for your map function.  Proper code indentation is helpful to find errors like this.

---

If that's truly the way you want it though, then this is what the error is pointing out. You currently have a code that looks a bit like this:

```
  if (item.Feedbacks.length > 0) { 
    return (<Panel>...</Panel>) 
  } 

  return (<div className="container text-center">...</div>) 

  else { 
    return (<h6>...</h6>) 
  }
```

That middle return statement makes the else statement unreachable.

You would need to edit with something like an `else if` for that middle return statement or place the else clause above the middle return statement.

Though this is a little broader than your question, it might actually solve it. It looks like those other statements shouldn't be in your `map` function at all.